# Free Heatmap software for iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ios, analytics, heatmap

I need to analyze my iPad application in terms of usability. I think the best way to do it is using heatmaps analytics. Do you know of any good one for iOS that would be free?

Comment: You mean data capture or the analytic side?

Answer (score 3):

I used [heatma.ps](https://heatma.ps). Its pretty easy to install, and they have a free plan.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [www.uxcam.com](http://www.uxcam.com), it provides heatmaps along with session replay.